# check if website shortcut icon on iphone exist first

Tags: ios, iphone, wordpress

following this tutorial, I'm able to add Iphone shortcut to my website

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-give-your-website-an-ios-home-screen-icon--webdesign-10067

is there a way to check if the icon already exist on the device before notifying the user to add the shortcut ?

Comment: The short answer is `no`